# Laravel api Login giving wrong feedback message

Tags: laravel

In my Project I am using Laravel-8, laravel-passport and spatie-permission for restful api. Already, I have this code in the Controller.

I have this controller

```
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
    if (auth('web')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        $user = Auth::guard('web')->user();
      //  dd($user);
        if (!$user->hasRole('Super Admin')) {
            return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error'=>'Unauthorised']);
        }

        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;

        return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User login successfully.');
    }
    else{
        return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error'=>'Unauthorised']);
    }
}:
```

'Super Admin' is part of the current user's role, yet I am getting this feedback:

> {"success":false,"message":"Unauthorised.","data":{"error":"Unauthorised"}}

It has to do with this line:

```
if (!$user->hasRole('Super Admin')) {
  return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error'=>'Unauthorised']);
}


CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `guard_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `roles` (`id`, `name`, `guard_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
VALUES
(1, 'Super Admin', 'web', '2019-11-13 12:11:38', NULL),
(2, 'Employee', 'web', '2019-11-13 12:11:38', NULL),
(3, 'HOD', 'web', '2019-11-13 12:11:38', NULL);


CREATE TABLE `model_has_roles` (
  `role_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `model_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `model_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `model_has_roles` (`role_id`, `model_type`, `model_id`) VALUES
(1, 'App\\Models\\User', 1),
(2, 'App\\Models\\User', 1);
```

What could be the problem and how do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain the authenticated user has that role, what is the output from `auth()->user()->getRoleNames();`? You should get a collection of all the roles assigned to the user.

Comment: @Unflux -  Auth::guard('web')->user()->getRoleNames(); gives Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1348
  #items: []
}  while  auth()->user()->getRoleNames(); gives: Error: Call to a member function getRoleNames() on null      I have dump my DB. It is there for the specified user. Thanks